# Adjusting bar and figsize after plotting bar with twinx

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I want to plot a bar next to other bars using the same x-axis, but a different y-axis. The bar 'D' in this example will be a percentage, so the scale is quite different.

- How can I move the new bar so that it is formatted the same as the other two bars plotted on the first axis?
- How can I adjust the figure size to keep the proportions constant?
- How can I update the legend?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random as r
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(1,11,size=(5,4)), columns=list('ABCD'))
df['A'] = list('abcde')
df['D'] = np.random.rand(5,1)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(0)
ax = df.loc[:,~df.columns.isin(['D'])].plot(kind='bar', x='A', figsize=(15,7))
ax2 = ax.twinx()
ax2.bar(df.A,df.D, color='g', width=.1)
```

Finally, I typically use the following code to remove the xlabel, but with a twinx, it removes the plot as well.

```
rl = plt.axes()
rl.xaxis.label.set_visible(False)
```

- How can I remove the x-label?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can draw the following graph in one line below, does this match what you intend to do, if you don't need xticks, please remove x='A'.

```
df.plot(x='A', kind='bar', figsize=(15,7), secondary_y='D')
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close to what I intend, thank you. Is there a way to adjust the ylim of the secondary axis? `set_ylim()` only works with the primary axis.